# How to prevent duplication of code

Tags: magento

We're currently developing an E-commerce site. We have a public and admin module.

Sometimes we offer the same functionality in both modules like viewing of products or creating of orders. But there are also some functionalities that is present in either public or admin like adding of products (which is in admin).

Our problem is that common functionalities lead to duplication of logic. We need to implement it in both modules.

One way of solving the problem is to make use of layers. So what we did was move the common logic into the Model. However, the controller is still duplicating codes like the one shown below:

```
public function invoice() {
    $this->Invoice->create();

    $this->Invoice->setCustomer($this->getCurrentUser);

    $invoice_items = // get list of items from post
    $this->Invoice->setItems($invoice_items);

    $this->Invoice->save();
}
```

My question is, is it wise to create a webservice that will encapsulate this logic and you just have to call it from the admin and public modules..

How does Magento implement the public and admin panels. And how does it manage its logic..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to do that. From your question, it is not exactly clear what sort of 'logic' are you referring to, but it does not seem too complex from your example. In general, business logic should be coded within the Model, controller, or Helper portions of the code. It can even reside in a separate extension as long as you set dependencies properly in the main xml file of the extension.

It seems that you may benefit from placing your logic in a helper class. The default helper file resides under /app/code/community/company/extension-name/Helper/Data.php. Then you can call the helper method anywhere in the backend (Block, Module, or controllers) by using this piece of code:

```
Mage::helper('extension-name')->getLogic()
```

Or you can call the same helper method from the view (phtml files) like this:

```
$this->helper('extension-name')->getLogic()
```